# Why $\cos(4\cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})) = \frac{x^4}{2} -2x^2+1$ $?$

Tags: trigonometry

In general how can I get from such an expression $\cos(a\cos^{-1}(x))$, or $\cos(a\sin^{-1}(x))$ to an expression of $x$?

Notice the constant $a$, because I know what happens without the constant. But I can't figure out how to do it with the constant in there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you may apply the double angle formula for cosine: $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$.  Thus $$\cos\left(4\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=2\cos^2\left(2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-1=2\left(2\cos^2\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-1\right)^2-1=2\left(2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2-1\right)^2-1=2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-1\right)^2-1=2\left(\frac{x^4}{4}-x^2+1\right)-1=\frac{x^4}{2}-2x^2+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is a nonnegative integer, $\cos(a t) = T_a(\cos(t))$ where $T_a$ is a [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind, so $\cos(a \arccos(x)) = T_a(x)$.